# How to solve a dependency error while adding english_words in pubspec file

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add english_words:

> ^3.1.5 (english_words 3.1.5 or higher) to the dependencies list but cannot add.

However I am getting an error:

[image: error]

Comment: You need to add that package under `dependencies:` section

Comment: The error you have attached does not show the error part that is needed. But as @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα said, move the line below the cupertino_icons

Comment: Please share all code in text form

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Move `english_words` to `dependencies` not `dev_dependencies` 
Step 2: Your indent is incorrect, please change from

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    english_words: ^3.1.5
```

to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```